# Mysql - most optimal way (performance and scalability) to store and retrieve multiple lines of text

Tags: php, mysql, text, varchar

I would like to store large amounts of lines of text into mysql. I've researched this, but i wasn't able to find an answer. Some of the answers I found include:

1. Create a varchar column and store all the text them there.
2. Read and write to a text file. That text file is located on a disk, and mysql keeps the path of that text file.
3. Read and write to a php file using an array. That php file is located on a disk, and mysql keeps the path of that php file.

But I'm not sure what are the pros and cons of each.

For my specific purpose, I would like to constantly add lines. This will eventually create a LARGE number of lines.

Ex.

```
Line 1: Hello World...........
Line 2: Hello World...........
Line 3: Hello World...........
Line 4: Hello World...........
...
Line 50,450: Hello World......
```

What would be the most optimal solution - performance wise, if I were using php to read and write lines?

I would like to do something like:

Read and display the first ten lines. When the user presses the "more" button, the next ten lines of text would be read and displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be looking for `pagination` in php using a mysql query like `SELECT * FROM table_name LIMIT $start, $limit`.

Here is an [example](http://runnable.com/U8dzQWEzMxxqeQ_E/php-pagination-example-using-mysql-database-for-dbms), this uses mysql_query, but you can substitute that with PDO. You can also use [redis](http://ls.pwd.io/2014/07/efficient-paging-with-mysql-and-redis-ordered-sets/), if you want to cache your results, so that you don't have to query the database every-time.